CORS issues with images in dotnet middleware pipeline
The situation is the following:

There are some TIF(F) files on the server
Users expect them to see them
To overcome the problem, we utilize an additional tool that converts TIF files to JPG assuming that JPG has the same file name except its extension
Front-end sends HEAD requests to probe if there is a JPG available for a specific TIF file

The part of the pipeline looks the following:
app.UseCors(p => p
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithOrigins(builder.Configuration.GetAllowedOrigins())
    .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition"));

app.UseStaticFiles();

var storageSettings = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<StorageSettings>>().Value;

if (storageSettings.EnableDocumentProvider)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, storageSettings.AttachmentsPath)),
        RequestPath = $"/{AttachmentsManager.VirtualPath}"
    });

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, storageSettings.DownloadsPath)),
        RequestPath = $"/{DownloadsManager.VirtualPath}"
    });
}

CORS worked fine before I introed these HEAD request for images, right now it works only when cache is disabled.
I tried to see what would happen if I did the following and it worked. I didn't like the solution, but at least the issue was gone.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, storageSettings.AttachmentsPath)),
    RequestPath = $"/{AttachmentsManager.VirtualPath}",
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //This is what I added
    }
});

Then I implemented a small middleware that appends required headers for only allowed origins. It was a shaky solution as I had also to rely on referer header.
public sealed class StaticFilesCorsMiddleware(IConfiguration configuration) : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly string[] _allowedOrigins = configuration.GetAllowedOrigins();

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var currentOrigin = context.Request.Headers.Origin.ToString().TrimEnd('/');
        var currentReferer = context.Request.Headers.Referer.ToString().TrimEnd('/');
        var effectiveCaller = string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentOrigin) ? currentReferer : currentOrigin;

        if (_allowedOrigins.Contains(effectiveCaller) && !context.Response.Headers.AccessControlAllowOrigin.Any())
        {
            context.Response.Headers.AccessControlAllowOrigin = effectiveCaller;
        }

        await next(context);
    }
}

And then I finally found out that I could just provide crossOrigin="anonymous" to image tags, which solved all the issues.
Now I cannot understand why it used to work without any crossOrigin attributes before I introduced HEAD requests
P.S. It is worth mentioning that exactly HEAD requests are failing without any fixes, not the actual requests for <img> tags.
It makes me think that the following order is applied:

Non-cached HEAD request via fetch (CORS headers sent/received)
Non-cached GET request for <img> tag is done (no CORS headers sent/received)
GET got cached
Next HEAD request fails due to missing headers in the cache (???)



I think it's just that your "crossOrigin" attribute is forcing a preflight?  That would probably cancel the browser's usual checks for cache/staleness of cache.  I don't understand why you are seeing two different errors for your fetches there.  They both should require preflight.

Is one of those requests same origin and the other not?

@browsermator, do you mean why there are two requests on the screen? It's because of the auth package used in FE, it intercepts all requests and passes them through WebWorker. Both requests are cross-origin

can you show what the errors are in those two failed requests?

I don't seem to be able to patch library to catch the actual exception, but it's just "Access to fetch at one-origin from another-origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

you may want to check if HEAD and/or OPTIONS verbs are actually accepted.  Right now the target server isn't sending any CORS headers.  Sometimes you need to install CORS module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module  You should also check if IIS is configured to use HEAD verb.

These verbs are accepted by the server and we don't use IIS. I see that headers are sent (for the first HEAD request), but without "crossOrigin" attribute the browser caches the image (GET request) without these headers (they aren't sent here), so the consequent HEAD request fails due to missing headers.
